# Can I sell my modified version of lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, custom-distributions, license

I've recently developed a piece of software that runs on top of lubuntu as a bootable maintenance tool. Can I legally sell my modified version of lubuntu and make a profit off of the operating system with my software preloaded onto it? I would be selling a download of the modified .iso or .img file with my software preinstalled for people to use.

I found [this](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing) legal document, but it wasn't clear about this topic.

Does my software have to be open source for me to legally sell it?

Comment: You can sell it as long as you give Ubuntu credit (I've also read it somewhere so you might need to do more research)

Answer (score 2):

As stated on the [Ubuntu licensing page](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing):

> “Ubuntu is a collection of thousands of computer programs and documents created by a range of individuals, teams and companies.
>
> Each of these programs may come under a different licence. This licence policy describes the process that we follow in determining which software will be included by default in the Ubuntu operating system.
>
> …
>
> While Ubuntu will not charge licence fees for this distribution, you might want to charge to print Ubuntu CDs, or create your own customised versions of Ubuntu which you sell, and should have the freedom to do so.”